# replace host in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am creating a website which is located in /shop/ on my webserver. It has a seperate domain.

Now, I want to change every request that comes in.

http://techinf.de/shop/ shall become http://holzwerkstatt-osel.de/ and
http://www.techinf.de/shop/ shall become http://www.holzwerkstatt-osel.de/

the actual request, like product.php?id=2 must be the same.

Comment: I believe, You need htaccess redirection: Redirect 301 /oldpage.html http://www.example.com/newpage.html

Comment: yup, i know. unfortunately i need not only one page to redirect but many

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to persist the `www` (or lackthereof), you likely do need to use `mod_rewrite` for this. The following should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?technif\.de$
RewriteRule ^shop/(.*)$ http://%1holzwerkstatt-osel.de/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Edit**: If you don't care about the whole `www` thing, just using `mod_alias` on `technif.de` should work:

```
Redirect permanent /shop http://holzwerkstatt-osel.de
```

This takes everything after `/shop` and appends it to the redirection URL, then redirects. So `/shop/product.php?id=2` becomes `http://holzwerkstatt-osel.de/product.php?id=2`, etc.

Comment: actually i dont care if there is redirection to holzwerkstatt with or without www